# how to create temporary url for custom storage in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I make a disk in filesystem like:

```
'avatars' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => storage_path('app/avatars')
        ],
```

is it possible / how can I ,create a temporary URL for files in this disk?
i tried

`return Storage::disk('avatars')->temporaryUrl('pp12.jpeg', now()->addMinutes(5));`

but its show me this error:

```
  RuntimeException
This driver does not support creating temporary URLs.
```

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Add the following code in the AppServiceProvider boot method.

```
Storage::disk('local')->buildTemporaryUrlsUsing(function ($path, $expiration, $options) {
        return URL::temporarySignedRoute(
            'local.temp',
            $expiration,
            array_merge($options, ['path' => $path])
        );
    });
```

Step 2: Add the route in web.php

```
Route::get('local/temp/{path}', function (string $path){
return Storage::disk('local')->download($path);})->name('local.temp');
```

This will allow downloading of the file using a temporary URL.

Now you can easily generate a temporary URL for the local disk.

```
disk = Storage::disk('releases-local');
return $disk->temporaryUrl($this->path, now()->addMinutes(5));
```

Comment: You should wrap the route definition with the `signed` middleware, otherwise the signature is not checked and the file is basically public

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-urls), and by the error message, temporary URLs are a feature of the S3 driver, and are not supported on any other driver.

If you don't want to use S3 to store your files (and you should probably consider doing so since it's a cheap and flexible way of hosting large numbers of files), then you will need to add this functionality yourself by creating a custom route that makes the file available for a limited period of time.

There's a number of ways you could achieve this depending on your use case, but I'd suggest looking into JWT - you can generate a JWT that expires after the appropriate time period, include the JWT in the URL as a query parameter, get the token in the route, and use it to prevent access to that route after the token has expired.

Comment: I use jwt to login and authentication stuff...
but how to use jwt for files? do you have any docs or tutorial for this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any resources for that, but it shouldn't be hard. You'd need to create a route that uniquely identifies a resource, such as using an ID of some kind, and have it also accept the token as a query parameter. If the JWT was invalid or expired, reject the request. If it's valid, and identifies a user who has permission to see the file, return it. Then just create a URL that leads to that route and includes the token as a query parameter. It will be dependent on the implementation you are using, and you'll need to dig into Laravel's permission system, but it's possible